# Create a NSDate with a user selected time in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, time, calendar, nsdate

```
int hour = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue]; //hour = 17
int min = [[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue]; //min = 51
NSLog(@"hour value is %d",hour);
NSLog(@"min value is %d",min);
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

int year = [components year];
int month = [components month];
int day = [components day];
NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;

[components setYear:year];
[components setMonth:month];
[components setDay:day];
[components setHour:hour];
[components setMinute:min];
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
NSDate *itemDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"the date is %@",itemDate);
```

Output:
the date is 2012-11-03 01:00:00 +0000 . But i want the output to be 2012-11-03 17:51:00..how can i get it?What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `NSLog("%@", array);` at the top of your method.  I suspect that your starting values aren't correct since the rest should work.

Comment: @Inafziger.Thanks. I added the logs for hour and min and they show 19 and 59 respectively. Because the time i tested is now. 7:59 P.M PST. ANd the output i got for "the date is  2012-11-03 02:57:00 +0000".

Comment: I just ran this on my system and manually set hour and min to 17 and 51.  My output was:  `2012-11-02 23:16:29.788 Testing App[99155:fb03] the date is 2012-11-02 21:51:00 +0000` (which is 4 hours off due to my time zone) which works exactly as it should.

Comment: @Inafziger. Yes i am using ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your issue is a simple matter of not realizing that the `NSDate` object will be created using your own current timezone but the `NSLog` will print out the `NSDate` description using UTC. Since you appear to be in PDT (it will be PST later this weekend when the clocks change in the USA), your `NSLog` should show the desired date/time but it will appear to be 7 hours (8 hours later this weekend) off.

To show your date in the local timezone, use an `NSDateFormatter` to convert the `NSDate` to an `NSString`.

Comment: @rmaddy.Thanks a lot buddy.Yes it was off by 7 hours exactly.So i took your advise and used NSDateFormatter to get the date in local timezone. +1 for explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"the date is %@", dateString);
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Used your example and rmaddy explanation to get it worked.